# Android getting layout width & height for Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

how to get the actual size values with compose? if something with the layout size has to be done before feeding the data to the view? i don't like checking. when everytime the canvas redraws

```
    Box {
        var count by rememberSaveable {
            mutableStateOf(0)
        }
        var states = remember { mutableListOf<Rain>() }
        Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            // i need the canvas' size so i initialize the object inside this scope, and check it every time when canvas redraws
            Log.e("canvas", "repainted")
            if(states.isEmpty()) states.addAll(MutableList(300) {
                Rain(size.width, size.height)
            })
            drawRect(color = Color.Black)
            repeat(300) {
                val c = count
                val x1 = states[it].x1
                val x2 = states[it].x2
                val y1 = states[it].y1
                val y2 = states[it].y2
                val color = states[it].color
                drawLine(start = Offset(x1, y1), end = Offset(x2, y2), color = color)
                states[it]()
            }
        }
        LaunchedEffect(isPaused) {
            while (!isPaused) {
                delay(40)
                count++
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save `canvasSize` into a state variable, and then use [`derivedStateOf`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#derivedstateof) for your `states`: content of this block will only be recalculated when any of mutable states used inside are changed, in this case it'll be `canvasSize`

```
Box {
    var count by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf(0)
    }
    var canvasSize by remember { mutableStateOf(Size.Unspecified) }
    val states by remember(canvasSize) {
        derivedStateOf {
            List(300) {
                Rain(canvasSize.width, canvasSize.height)
            }
        }
    }
    Canvas(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        canvasSize = size
        drawRect(color = Color.Blue)
        repeat(300) {
            val x1 = states[it].x1
            val x2 = states[it].x2
            val y1 = states[it].y1
            val y2 = states[it].y2
            drawLine(start = Offset(x1, y1), end = Offset(x2, y2), color = color)
        }
        states[it]()
    }
    LaunchedEffect(isPaused) {
        while (!isPaused) {
            delay(40)
            count++
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: excuse me, i have no ideas how to create states inside drawScope using remember, compose invocations can only happen from the context of a Composable function , it says so. i have to implement my own one?

Comment: do you mean mutable state inside Canvas is all by itself a kind of remember?

Comment: @user16799920 I misunderstood your question, check the update

Comment: thanks, it does work. and it was wrong of my broken language which is hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

DrawScope where inside has some properties one of them being `size` which itself has **width**, **height**, **minDimension** and **maxDimension** properties.

```
Canvas {
       size.width
       size.height
}
```

others are

```
@DrawScopeMarker
interface DrawScope : Density {

    /**
     * The current [DrawContext] that contains the dependencies
     * needed to create the drawing environment
     */
    val drawContext: DrawContext

    /**
     * Center of the current bounds of the drawing environment
     */
    val center: Offset
        get() = drawContext.size.center

    /**
     * Provides the dimensions of the current drawing environment
     */
    val size: Size
        get() = drawContext.size

    /**
     * The layout direction of the layout being drawn in.
     */
    val layoutDirection: LayoutDirection
...
}
```